# Would a pressurized container move by itself if opposite edges have different size surface area?

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, pressure

If inside a closed container there is gas with higher pressure than outside the container, and one edge of the container has a larger surface area than the opposite side, would the container move by itself? Wouldn't there be a net force in one direction since one surface area is bigger than the opposite side while the pressure is the same?
[image: container]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are forgetting that the pressure on the two other slanted faces also contribute a component of force opposite to the largest face. The net forces still balance.

This is because the vector area (the integral of all infinitesimal area vectors) of any closed surface is zero.

Answer (score 1):

The world would be a lot more interesting if that were true!

No.  If you sum the normal forces over all sides of the shape, you'll see that the components in all directions still cancel to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your thinking is not correct. If we treat the whole box as a system, then box will move if and only if $\sum F_{ext}\neq0$.

However in your setup, it's shown that internal pressure (or intenral forces) is somehow moving the box, which cannot be possible. The internal forces must cancel each other out in this case.